# Automatically open an application when Bluetooth is tuned on

Tags: windows, script, bluetooth

I want an application to execute when my Bluetooth turns on. And also if possible to close the app if Bluetooth turns off.

Comment: is this for a phone or ur laptop?

Comment: Is there an event in the System Event Log when your device is turned on or off?

Comment: It is for the laptop @Prasanna